# How to store and retrieve a dictionary with redis

Tags: python, redis

```
# I have the dictionary my_dict
my_dict = {
    'var1' : 5
    'var2' : 9
}
r = redis.StrictRedis()
```

How would I store my_dict and retrieve it with redis.  For example, the following code does not work.

```
#Code that doesn't work
r.set('this_dict', my_dict)  # to store my_dict in this_dict
r.get('this_dict')  # to retrieve my_dict
```

Comment: Redis is used as a data lake here. If you don't need individual key:value pairs at retrieval time time, you can use Parquet in MinIO / S3, will be faster and more scalable (to petabytes rather than gigabytes).

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You can do it by `hmset` (multiple keys can be set using `hmset`).

`hmset("RedisKey", dictionaryToSet)`

```
import redis
conn = redis.Redis('localhost')

user = {"Name":"Pradeep", "Company":"SCTL", "Address":"Mumbai", "Location":"RCP"}

conn.hmset("pythonDict", user)

conn.hgetall("pythonDict")

{'Company': 'SCTL', 'Address': 'Mumbai', 'Location': 'RCP', 'Name': 'Pradeep'}
```

Comment: if it is nested data structure rather than simply dict, e.g containing some arrays etc. serialzie your data with `json.dumps()` write as string and after retrive from redis user `json.loads()` for deserializing it back to python data structure

Comment: `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()` will only work if you are fine with your dictionary keys always being strings. If you aren't then you might consider using pickle.

Comment: json is not compatible with bytes so json serilization is not a global solution, e.g., if you have a dict with a bytes value this will not work.

Comment: By way of note, the documentation for `hmset` does not tell you this, but it raises a DataError if you try to store an empty dict.

Comment: @Pradeep how we can make the key dynamic. suppose the data is getting inserted every 15 minute so how i can make the key dynamic

Comment: @ak3191 you can generate a GUID.

Comment: Be warned that the underlying Redis command `HMSET` [has been deprecated](https://redis.io/commands/hmset) (moved to a different function) in version 4.0.0 (July 2017) but `redis-py` still executes it [here in hmset()](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/redis/client.html#Redis.hmset).

Comment: This method is deprecated. Use hset instead. But with the new function hset. Dictionary cannot be used anymore.

Comment: this doesn't work with native datetime objects either

Comment: pickle can be dangerous if mishandled. Use msgpack for better serialization of data before storing it into redis.

Answer (score 46):

you can pickle your dict and save as string.

```
import pickle
import redis

r = redis.StrictRedis('localhost')
mydict = {1:2,2:3,3:4}
p_mydict = pickle.dumps(mydict)
r.set('mydict',p_mydict)

read_dict = r.get('mydict')
yourdict = pickle.loads(read_dict)
```

Comment: This is true, but depending on the rate of reads and writes, this may add serious overhead. Pickling is a slow operation

Comment: Please note that if this is used with user input your server [is prone to remote code exection](https://davidhamann.de/2020/04/05/exploiting-python-pickle/), `pickle.loads` is should only be used on 100% trusted data

Comment: pickle can be dangerous if mishandled. Use msgpack for better serialization of data before storing it into Redis.

Comment: Pickling has also the important down-part that you cannot debug the stored data in Redis as they are binary.

Comment: In python3 + redis 3.x, i had to use `pickle.dumps(mydict, protocol=0)` and `pickle.loads(str.encode(read_dict))`

Answer (score 26):

As the basic answer has already give by other people, I would like to add some to it.

Following are the commands in `REDIS` to perform basic operations with `HashMap/Dictionary/Mapping` type values.

1. HGET => Returns value for single key passed
2. HSET => set/updates value for the single key
3. HMGET => Returns value for single/multiple keys passed
4. HMSET => set/updates values for the multiple key
5. HGETALL => Returns all the (key, value) pairs in the mapping.

Following are their respective methods in `redis-py` library :-

1. HGET => hget
2. HSET => hset
3. HMGET => hmget
4. HMSET => hmset
5. HGETALL => hgetall

All of the above setter methods creates the mapping, if it doesn't exists.
All of the above getter methods doesn't raise error/exceptions, if mapping/key in mapping doesn't exists.

```
Example:
=======
In [98]: import redis
In [99]: conn = redis.Redis('localhost')

In [100]: user = {"Name":"Pradeep", "Company":"SCTL", "Address":"Mumbai", "Location":"RCP"}

In [101]: con.hmset("pythonDict", {"Location": "Ahmedabad"})
Out[101]: True

In [102]: con.hgetall("pythonDict")
Out[102]:
{b'Address': b'Mumbai',
 b'Company': b'SCTL',
 b'Last Name': b'Rajpurohit',
 b'Location': b'Ahmedabad',
 b'Name': b'Mangu Singh'}

In [103]: con.hmset("pythonDict", {"Location": "Ahmedabad", "Company": ["A/C Pri
     ...: sm", "ECW", "Musikaar"]})
Out[103]: True

In [104]: con.hgetall("pythonDict")
Out[104]:
{b'Address': b'Mumbai',
 b'Company': b"['A/C Prism', 'ECW', 'Musikaar']",
 b'Last Name': b'Rajpurohit',
 b'Location': b'Ahmedabad',
 b'Name': b'Mangu Singh'}

In [105]: con.hget("pythonDict", "Name")
Out[105]: b'Mangu Singh'

In [106]: con.hmget("pythonDict", "Name", "Location")
Out[106]: [b'Mangu Singh', b'Ahmedabad']
```

I hope, it makes things more clear.

Comment: how you can make the key dynamic

Answer (score 24):

If you want to store a python dict in redis, it is better to store it as json string.

```
import json
import redis

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
mydict = { 'var1' : 5, 'var2' : 9, 'var3': [1, 5, 9] }
rval = json.dumps(mydict)
r.set('key1', rval)
```

While retrieving de-serialize it using json.loads

```
data = r.get('key1')
result = json.loads(data)
arr = result['var3']
```

*What about types (eg.bytes) that are not serialized by json functions ?*

You can write encoder/decoder functions for types that cannot be serialized by json functions. eg. writing base64/ascii encoder/decoder function for byte array.

Comment: I downvoted this because some dicts cannot be serialized to JSON, for example, dicts with a bytes value.

Comment: You can write an encoder/decoder function (according to the requirement, eg. base64/ascii encoding) for the types that cannot be encoded/decoded by default.

Comment: @Tommy - even if use hmset/hgetall , you might need to encode/decode types that are not supported by redis.

Comment: Disagreeing about  " ... latter operation is O(N)."
N being the number of fields you have link to the key. Doing N SET/GET or 1 HGET/HSET is the same complexity. See : https://redis.io/commands/hmset
Time-wise, HGET/HSET are atomic transaction, and so are performed faster by REDIS.
You are just moving the complexity from Redis to Python Code.

Comment: The advantage of hmset is the possiblity to retrieve only certain sub-parts of the dict. With json we lose that, so this is as good as pickle or other thing.

Comment: The import json is missing.

Comment: @thanos.a I agree - added it.

Answer (score 22):

HMSET is deprecated per the [Redis docs](https://redis.io/commands/hset). You can now use `HSET` with a dictionary as follows:

```py
import redis

r = redis.Redis('localhost')
    
key = "hashexample" 
entry = { 
    "version":"1.2.3", 
    "tag":"main", 
    "status":"CREATED",  
    "timeout":"30"
}
r.hset(key, mapping=entry)
```

---

Caution: very unintuitively, `hset` won't accept a dictionary (raising an error suggesting it does not accept dictionaries, see [1]) if it is simply passed to the 2nd positional (unnamed) argument. You need to pass the dictionary to a **named** argument `mapping=`.

```
[1] *** redis.exceptions.DataError: Invalid input of type: 'dict'. Convert to a bytes, string, int or float first.
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm trying to find the doc where all this is spelled out.  Do you know where it is.  For example, what are the two "Nones" for.

Comment: @NealWalters: See the line on the HMSET command page - https://redis.io/commands/hmset for deprecation warning.

Comment: @Tad Guski, how to you expire hashexample?

Answer (score 17):

Another way: you can use `RedisWorks` library.

`pip install redisworks`

```
>>> from redisworks import Root
>>> root = Root()
>>> root.something = {1:"a", "b": {2: 2}}  # saves it as Hash type in Redis
...
>>> print(root.something)  # loads it from Redis
{'b': {2: 2}, 1: 'a'}
>>> root.something['b'][2]
2
```

It converts python types to Redis types and vice-versa.

```
>>> root.sides = [10, [1, 2]]  # saves it as list in Redis.
>>> print(root.sides)  # loads it from Redis
[10, [1, 2]]
>>> type(root.sides[1])
<class 'list'>
```

Disclaimer: I wrote the library. Here is the code: https://github.com/seperman/redisworks

Comment: By way of note, RedisWorks uses `hmset` under the hood if you set a variable to a dict, and thus if you do `root.something = {}` you will get a DataError, because `hmset` doesn't allow empty dictionaries. I mention this because the documentation for redis doesn't tell you this.

Comment: Interesting. Yes it does use `hmset`. I will look into this. @hlongmore

Comment: But still, can it support bytes in dictionary ?

Comment: BTW, Redis.hmset() is deprecated. you should use Redis.hset() instead.

Comment: Yeah I need to fix it when I get a chance... PR's are very welcome too!

Answer (score 8):

One might consider using [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/index.html)  which is endorsed by redis.

```
import msgpack

data = {
    'one': 'one',
    'two': 2,
    'three': [1, 2, 3]
}

await redis.set('my-key', msgpack.packb(data))
val = await redis.get('my-key')
print(msgpack.unpackb(val))

# {'one': 'one', 'two': 2, 'three': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Using [msgpack-python](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-python) and [aioredis](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis)

Answer (score 6):

The redis SET command stores a string, not arbitrary data. You could try using the redis HSET command to store the dict as a redis hash with something like

```
for k,v in my_dict.iteritems():
    r.hset('my_dict', k, v)
```

but the redis datatypes and python datatypes don't quite line up. Python dicts can be arbitrarily nested, but a redis hash is going to require that your value is a string. Another approach you can take is to convert your python data to string and store that in redis, something like

```
r.set('this_dict', str(my_dict))
```

and then when you get the string out you will need to parse it to recreate the python object.

Comment: he can convert his data to json and store the result in redis

Answer (score 4):

An other way you can approach the matter:

```
import redis
conn = redis.Redis('localhost')

v={'class':'user','grants': 0, 'nome': 'Roberto', 'cognome': 'Brunialti'}

y=str(v)
print(y['nome']) #<=== this return an error as y is actually a string
conn.set('test',y)

z=eval(conn.get('test'))
print(z['nome']) #<=== this really works!
```

I did not test it for efficiency/speed.

Answer (score 4):

> DeprecationWarning: Redis.hmset() is deprecated. Use Redis.hset() instead.

Since HMSET is deprecated you can use HSET:

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, decode_responses=True)
r.hset('user:23', mapping={'id': 23, 'name': 'ip'})
r.hgetall('user:23')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know exactly how to organize data in Redis, I did some performance tests, including the results parsing.
The dictonary I used (**d**) had 437.084 keys (md5 format), and the values of this form:

```
{"path": "G:\tests\2687.3575.json",
 "info": {"f": "foo", "b": "bar"},
 "score": 2.5}
```

**First Test** (inserting data into a redis key-value mapping):

```
conn.hmset('my_dict', d)  # 437.084 keys added in 8.98s

conn.info()['used_memory_human']  # 166.94 Mb

for key in d:
    json.loads(conn.hget('my_dict', key).decode('utf-8').replace("'", '"'))
    #  41.1 s

import ast
for key in d:
    ast.literal_eval(conn.hget('my_dict', key).decode('utf-8'))
    #  1min 3s

conn.delete('my_dict')  # 526 ms
```

**Second Test** (inserting data directly into Redis keys):

```
for key in d:
    conn.hmset(key, d[key])  # 437.084 keys added in 1min 20s

conn.info()['used_memory_human']  # 326.22 Mb

for key in d:
    json.loads(conn.hgetall(key)[b'info'].decode('utf-8').replace("'", '"'))
    #  1min 11s

for key in d:
    conn.delete(key)
    #  37.3s
```

As you can see, in the second test, only 'info' values have to be parsed, because the hgetall(key) already returns a dict, but not a nested one.

And of course, the best example of using Redis as python's dicts, is the **First Test**

Answer (score 0):

Try [rejson-py](https://github.com/RedisLabs/rejson-py) which is relatively new since 2017. Look at this [introduction](https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-as-a-json-store/).

```
from rejson import Client, Path

rj = Client(host='localhost', port=6379)

# Set the key `obj` to some object
obj = {
    'answer': 42,
    'arr': [None, True, 3.14],
    'truth': {
        'coord': 'out there'
    }
}
rj.jsonset('obj', Path.rootPath(), obj)

# Get something
print 'Is there anybody... {}?'.format(
    rj.jsonget('obj', Path('.truth.coord'))
)

# Delete something (or perhaps nothing), append something and pop it
rj.jsondel('obj', Path('.arr[0]'))
rj.jsonarrappend('obj', Path('.arr'), 'something')
print '{} popped!'.format(rj.jsonarrpop('obj', Path('.arr')))

# Update something else
rj.jsonset('obj', Path('.answer'), 2.17)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the JSON format for a python dict, It is the standard according to the [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/json/) and fairly simple.

```py
import redis

data = {
    'dog': {
        'scientific-name' : 'Canis familiaris'
    }
}

r = redis.Redis()
r.json().set('doc', '$', data)
doc = r.json().get('doc', '$')
dog = r.json().get('doc', '$.dog')
scientific_name = r.json().get('doc', '$..scientific-name')
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. convert the dictionary to string (str)
> 2. Deserialize the dictionary (eval)

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis(port=6310, decode_responses=True)
mydict = str({ 'var1' : 5, 'var2' : 9, 'var3': [1, 5, 9] })

r.set('key1', mydict)

value = eval(r.get('key1'))
```

> Hope it help. This is a python code

Answer (score -1):

Lots of good answers but this worked for me.

- store dictionary
- get dictionary
- nested hash instead of mapping the dict as key to field and value to value like other answers above. (see example 1)
- get all field/values and go from there as normally you would in a project where you want to dump a dict to a redis hash where the dict is a nested hash. (see example 2)

note: these commands were done in the python repl

1. if you want

```py
{'field1': 'Hello', 'field2': 'World'}
```

[image]

Use

```py
r = redis.Redis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)
pdict = {'field1': 'Hello', 'field2': 'World'}
r.hmset("queues_test", pdict)
```

Also refer to other answers, particularly Saji Xavier's since its simple and works.

If you want a nested hash like

```py
{'queue1': '{"field1": "Hello", "field2": "World"}'
```

[image]

then

```py
# to set
import json
r = redis.Redis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)
pdict = {'field1': 'Hello', 'field2': 'World'}
pdict_string = json.dumps(pdict)
r.hset("queues_data", "queue1", pdict_string)

# to get a single field value
r.hget("queues_data", "queue1")
# '{"field1": "Hello", "field2": "World"}'

# to get all fields
data =  r.hgetall("queues_data")
# {'queue1': '{"field1": "Hello", "field2": "World"}'
queue1 = data['queue1']
queue1
# '{"field1": "Hello", "field2": "World"}'

result = json.loads(queue1)
result
# {'field1': 'Hello', 'field2': 'World'}
result['field1']
# 'Hello'
```

Then if you just need the keys/values

```py
list(data.keys())
# ['queue1', 'queue2']

list(data.values())
# ['{"field1": "Hello", "field2": "World"}', '{"field1": "Hello", "field2": "World"}']
```

Then if you want get the dict back for all values in one line use

```py
lvalues = list(data.values()) 
# ['{"field1": "Hello", "field2": "World"}', '{"field1": "Hello", "field2": "World"}']

[json.loads(x) for x in lvalues]
# [{'field1': 'Hello', 'field2': 'World'}, {'field1': 'Hello', 'field2': 'World'}]
```