# Alternative to a very large dictionary (~40 million keys)

Tags: python, large-files, shelve, large-data

I have a rather large dictionary with about 40 million keys which I naively stored just by writing `{key: value, key: value, ...}` into a text file. I didn't consider the fact that I could never realistically access this data because python has an aversion to loading and evaluating a 1.44GB text file as a dictionary.

I know I could use something like `shelve` to be able to access the data without reading all of it at once, but I'm not sure how I would even convert this text file to a shelve file without regenerating all the data (which I would prefer not to do). Are there any better alternatives for storing, accessing, and potentially later changing this much data? If not, how should I go about converting this monstrosity over to a format usable by shelve?

If it matters, the dictionary is of the form `{(int, int, int int): [[int, int], Bool]}`

Comment: Use a database?

Comment: Use sqlite - Python has good support for it in the standard library.

Comment: To add to the comment by Alexander, [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html) is probably the lowest barrier to entry ...

Answer (score 1):

[Redis](https://redis.io/) is a in-memory key-value store that can be used for this kind of problems.

There are several [Python clients](https://redis.io/clients#python).

[hmset](https://redis.io/commands/hmset) operation allows you to insert multiple key-values.

Comment: Took *hmset* idea from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276493/how-to-store-and-retrieve-a-dictionary-with-redis

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/dagnelies/pysos

https://github.com/dagnelies/pysos

It works like a normal python `dict`, but has the advantage that it's much more efficient than `shelve` on windows and is also cross-platform, unlike `shelve` where the data storage differs based on the OS.

To install:

```
pip install pysos
```

Usage:

```
import pysos
db = pysos.Dict('somefile')
db['hello'] = 'persistence!'
```

Just to give a ballpark figure, here is a mini benchmark (on my windows laptop):

```py
import pysos
t = time.time()
import time
N = 100 * 1000
db = pysos.Dict("test.db")
for i in range(N):
    db["key_" + str(i)] = {"some": "object_" + str(i)}
db.close()

print('PYSOS time:', time.time() - t)
# => PYSOS time: 3.424309253692627
```

The resulting file was about 3.5 Mb big.

So, in your case, if a million key/value pairs take roughly 1 minute to insert ...it would take you almost an hour to insert it all. Of course, the machine's specs can influence that a lot. It's just a *very* rough estimate.

Comment: Hey, I know that your answer was almost a year ago, but I am trying to use Pysos right now and I'm wondering how do I get the value at a key in Pysos.dict after inserting it. Is insertion and retrieval the same syntax: db[key]?

Comment: @AdamLee exactly