# Redis-py hset() mapping - TypeError when setting multiple item values

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I am building some very large lookup tables in Redis. I have some straightforward code that works as intended when looping through a dict to set a single value in my Redis hash (via a pipeline) for each item using `hset()`:

```
foo = {"1234": "5678", "abcd": "efgh", ... }

with self.db.pipeline() as pipe:
    for foo in bar:
        pipe.hset("lookup_table", foo["key"], foo["value"])
pipe.execute()
```

This is slow with a large dict. To speed it up, I want to be able to set multiple items as a mapping into the pipeline without having to loop over it. With `hmset()` now deprecated, it seems that `hset()` can accept a mapping via a keyword arg. I have attempted to do the following:

```
with self.db.pipeline() as pipe:    
    pipe.hset("lookup_table", mapping=foo)
pipe.execute()
```

but this yields the error `TypeError: hset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mapping'`. Am I using `hset()` incorrectly? Or am I mistaken in thinking that `hset()` can accept multiple items in this way?

I'm using py-redis 3.4.1 with Python 3.7.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue as shown here --> https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/issues/1310#issuecomment-603081122.

As you can see in that image linked, the source code in PyPi has `hset` with a function signature that *does not* include the keyword `mapping`. You should verify in your installation of `py-redis` that the same issue is present and follow that ticket as well. To work around it you can clone straight from `master` branch in order to use that feature.

Comment: Thanks, I had reviewed the source code on Github and saw that it was present in 3.4.1 and that I had 3.4.1 installed via pip, so thought it was the code that I was using. Installing from the Github repo solved the issue (and it is indeed much faster).

Answer (score 2):

Updating with

```
pip install -U redis
```

solved the issue for me.

Comment: A simple fix is always the best fix!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming later to find a better answer and example.

```py
# test mapping to add a full dict
foo = {"1234": "5678", "abcd": "efgh" }
queueLib.redis.hset("queues_data2", mapping=foo)
# works

import json
foo2 = {"1234": "5678", "abcd": {} }
queueLib.redis.hset("queues_data2", mapping=foo2)
# fails with
# redis.exceptions.DataError: Invalid input of type: 'dict'. Convert to a bytes, string, int or float first.

# if you try via serialization
pdict_string = json.dumps(foo2)
queueLib.redis.hset("queues_data2", mapping=pdict_string)
# fails with 
# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

# now try 
update_nested_dict = json.dumps(foo2['abcd'])
foo2['abcd'] = update_nested_dict
queueLib.redis.hset("queues_data2", mapping=foo2)

# you can also loop through each value of the dict and serialize it with something like:

foo3 = {"1234": {}, "abcd": {} }
{k: json.dumps(v) for k,v in foo3.items()}
# {'1234': '{}', 'abcd': '{}'}
```

Also covered more on handling dict with redis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75560199/9270352)